# How to connect to a redis database running in Docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

I'm trying to connect to a Redis instance running in Docker mapped to port 6379. I use the Redis library, typescript, and express. However, I do not even get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { createClient } from 'redis'
const redisClient = createClient({ url: "redis://localhost:6379" });
redisClient.on('error', err => console.error(err))
redisClient.once('open', () => console.log("Connected to Redis"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the connection succeeds by listening to `ready` event:

```
redisClient.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Connected to redis!');
});
```

From the `redis` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) page:

> client will emit `ready` once a connection is established. Commands issued before the ready event are queued, then replayed just before this event is emitted.

Comment: This one also does not log anything. And if I try to write some data I get "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The client is closed".

Comment: I don't know if you are exposing the ports correctly in your Dockerfile or not. If you want you can check out this project https://github.com/Ernyoke/stackoverflow-questions/tree/main/redis-node where I managed to connect to redis without issues.

Comment: thanks for the code. I do exactly the same. And if I try to go to the URL from my browser, redis gives an attacker warning in docker, so it is setup and up. But node won't connect for some reason